# MapStruct map correct instance of object based on target type

Tags: java, spring, jackson, jackson2, mapstruct

How to correct map different classes with same parent

**spring** DTO **jackson** objects

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type",
    )
@JsonSubTypes(value = {
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = B.class, name = "TypeB"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = C.class, name = "TypeC")
})
abstract class A {
   Type type;
   String id;
}


class B extends A {
    String name;  
}


class C extends A {
   String description;
}
```

Entity class contains all fields

```
class myEntity {
    Type type;
    String id;
    String name;  
    String description;
}
```

MapStruct mapper

```
public abstract class IntegrationMapper  {
    public A toDto(MyEntity myEntity);
    public MyEntity fromDto(A integrationDTO)  
}
```

How I can create different instances **B or C** into **toDto** depends on *type*  value ?

I use smth like that

```
public abstract class IntegrationMapper {
    public A toDto(MyEntity myEntity) {
        if(myEntity.type == TypeB) {
            return toB(myEntity);
        } else if (myEntity.type == TypeC) {
            return toC(myEntity);            
        }
    }

    public MyEntity fromDto(A a)  {
        if(a instanceOf B) {
            return fromDto((B) a);
        } else if (a instanceOf C) {
            return fromDto((C) a);
        }
    }

    protected B toB(MyEntity myEntity);
    protected C toC(MyEntity myEntity);

    protected MyEntity fromDto(B c);
    protected MyEntity fromDto(C c);

}
```

But I suspect that it can be done better with ObjectFactory or smth like that

to avoid long *if statement* and creation new method for each new child of **A**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform the mapping for the fields in `B` and `C` you will have to create methods for them. MapStruct is a code generation so it doesn't know anything about the runtime types.

Your current approach is the way to go for what you are looking for. I don't think that using `ObjectFactory` can help you out. The only way it can help you out is if you want to map `MyEntity` to the base `A`. In such case it will generate mapping only between the base and the entity, which is not what you are looking for.

There is an open feature request ([#131](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/131)) that can generate those instance of checks for you.